# MySql Update Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table in MySQL with following data

```
NAME    SEX  
A       Male  
B       Female  
C       Male  
A       Null  
B       Null  
C       Null  
D       Null
```

how can I update `SEX` from preceding rows?

Output:

```
NAME    SEX  
A       Male  
B       Female  
C       Male  
A       Male  
B       Female  
C       Male
D       Null
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you like the values to be?  An example of expected output would help...

Comment: Question is not clear, do you mean you want to update `A` which is null from the other `A` which has a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a name can have only one sex, you can update all other names that do not have a sex yet like:

```
update  YourTable yt1
join    (
        select  name
        ,       max(sex) as maxSex
        from    YourTable
        group by
                name
        ) yt2
on      yt1.name = yt2.name 
        and yt2.maxSex is not null
set     yt1.sex = yt2.maxSex
where   yt1.sex is null;
```

In your example, this will fill in the sex for each row except D, since there is no record with name D and a non-null sex.

Comment: It works fine. But there is an interesting thing. After running this query when I update any record in table manually in any IDE then it automatically updates all rows. Can you tell me please why is it?

Comment: @Novice: An update query has no effect after it's finished.  Check if there are triggers on your table?

Comment: I've checked triggers. I create another db and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set `Male` on all fields where `Null` is, just run a simple update:

```
UPDATE table SET SEX='Male' WHERE SEX IS NULL
```

If you want to do this automatically, you should insert an incrementing index column to refer to in your script.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, a query like this will be ok

UPDATE TABLE T SET SEX = (SELECT SEX FROM TABLE WHERE NAME = T.NAME LIMIT 1);

but mysql cannot use in a subquery a table used in update, so you have to use a ugly trick like this one:

[MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)